# TailwindCSS animation not working with dark variant

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying a to make a simple dark mode button that slides on clicking it.

For some reason when using the `dark:` option it does not work, but when using conditions in my classname is does.

Is there a way to make it work with the `dark:` without using conditions in my classes?

This is the working code:

```
    <button aria-hidden="true" className="relative focus:outline-none" onClick={() => { dispatch(ChangeTheme(!isDark)) }} >
     <div className={`w-12 h-6 transition rounded-full outline-none blackThemeColor bg-primary-100 dark:bg-white`}></div>
className={`absolute top-0 left-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center w-6 h-6 transition-all duration-150 transform scale-110 rounded-full shadow-sm ${!isDark ? 'translate-x-6 text-primary-100 blackThemeColor text-white' : 'translate-x-0 -translate-y-px bg-white text-primary-dark'}`}

     {!isDark ?
     <svg 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       fill="none"
       viewBox="0 0 24 24"
       stroke="currentColor">
       <path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth="2"
        d="M20.354 15.354A9 9 0 018.646 3.646 9.003 9.003 0 0012 21a9.003 9.003 0 008.354-5.646z"/></svg>
        :
         <svg
          className="dark:w-4 h-4"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke="currentColor">
         <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          strokeWidth="2"
         d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"/></svg>}
     </div>
    </button>
```

And when chaging this div, it does not work anymore:

```
<div className={`absolute top-0 left-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center w-6 h-6 transition-all duration-150 transform scale-110 rounded-full shadow-sm translate-x-6 text-primary-100 blackThemeColor text-white dark:translate-x-0 dark:-translate-y-px dark:bg-white dark:text-primary-dark'`}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already setup your `tailwind.config.js` accordingly, to allow toggling dark mode manually, you'll also need to enable the `dark` variant for the `translate-*` utilities.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    // ...
    variants: {
        extend: {
            // ...
            translate: ['dark'],
        }
    }
}
```

The `dark:` prefix needs to be applied to all the target classes individually.

```js
<div className={`absolute top-0 left-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center 
    w-6 h-6 transition-all duration-150 transform scale-110 rounded-full 
    shadow-sm translate-x-6 text-primary-100 blackThemeColor text-white 
    dark:translate-x-0 dark:-translate-y-px dark:bg-white dark:text-primary-dark`}>
```

Note that the `dark` class needs to be applied to the `<html>` tag for the `dark:` prefix to work. How you set that up is up to you, but you can check the [dark mode official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) for examples.

Comment: Hi, I also tried it but it still does not seem to be working

Comment: When you toggle the dark theme, is the `dark` class being applied to the `<html>` tag? That's required in order for the `dark:` prefix to work, have a read through the docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually.

Comment: yes it is, I do have other stuff on the page that are using the dark: and those work perfectly. even with dark mode slider the colors changes like expected, but the animations do not seem to work

Comment: Right, that means you'll need to enable the `dark` variant for the `translate` utility. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you, it was indeed the missing translate: ['dark']. is there a way to enable the dark on all variants?

Comment: Sadly there isn't. By default, it's enabled for: `backgroundColor`, `borderColor`, `gradientColorStops`, `placeholderColor`, and `textColor`. You'll have to enable it manually for other utilities you may need.